# uninstall / remove 18.04 hwe

Tags: 18.04, xrdp

After installing hwe in ubuntu 18.04 it screwed up my `xrdp` capability on my headless machine.

What is the proper procedure for removing `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` and `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`?

I have done the following `sudo apt remove linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`

Then I reverted my kernel back to 4.15

And `xrdp` seems to still not be able to show my desktop.

Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: can you show `sudo apt-get -s install --install-recommends linux-generic xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all libwayland-egl1-mesa` this is only a simulation. Edit your question for output, please.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep hwe` to the question.

Comment: answered this on related question: [https://askubuntu.com/a/1301706/242730](https://askubuntu.com/a/1301706/242730)

Answer (score 1):

it's fine I figured this out another way.

remove linux-headers-4.18.x
remove all of xserver-xorg-hwe

reinstall xserver-xorg

Comment: yes you are correct.