# Rolling back Linux 5.0 on 18.04 after installing HWE

Tags: 18.04, grub2, sound, kernel, suspend

When I found out the latest point release for 18.04 contained the 5.0 kernel, I got overzealous and installed it on my machine according to [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/436507/how-to-install-the-linux-5.0-update-on-ubuntu-18.04-lts/)'s instructions:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

However, ever since then, I've had a couple of problems such as audio not working ( I have to run `sudo alsa force-reload` nearly every boot ) and suspend has stopped working reliably.

Thus, I would like to roll back to the previous kernel.

My question is - can I just run the above command only with `remove`? or should I enable the `grub` menu and alter the default boot parameters? - or perhaps something completely different...?

Comment: Remember to report the bugs that you have discovered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**OP Edit:**

In my case, I needed a few more steps. You might not need to do this bit. 
When I went to uninstall the offending kernel(s) - I was not able to because I was currently booted into it - thus, apt/dpkg threw an error during removal. If you run into that, this is the remedy:

First, edit `/etc/default/grub`  from

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

to:

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
```

and naturally, run `sudo update-grub` afterward.

This way, you can boot into the older, working kernel, and the one you are currently on will uninstall without any fuss.

/end OP Edit

---

Yes, you may just run:

```
sudo apt remove linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

to remove the HWE kernel, under the assumption that you haven't removed the `linux-generic` metapackage. If you did remove it, run the following command to install it back:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

You would also want to remove the HWE images and headers that might have been left behind. To do this run the following commands to list all images and headers, respectively:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
dpkg --list | grep linux-headers
```

If there are any HWE images and headers remove them using:

```
sudo apt remove <image|header>
```

**OP Note: I did not have to do this step.**

Since you have also installed the HWE `xorg`, you may have to revert it to the non-HWE one. To do this run:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg
```

If you get a dependency error, just install the dependencies too.

Comment: Is it a good idea to remove `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` and not replace it with another kernel metapackage? (note - that was a rhetorical question. It is not a good idea).

Comment: I supposed that he hasn't removed the `linux-generic` package, since he doesn't mention it in the question. However, you are right. I will add this to my answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The guide he followed also doesn't remove the package.

Comment: Good edit, +1.  Best not to leave traps for the unwary.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sudo apt install xserver-xorg` as this is the relevant package and installing it will remove `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`. Remind that the hwe-kernel is a recommended package of `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`, so an upgrade of this package would reinstall the hwe-kernel.

Comment: I tried running `sudo apt install xserver-xorg` on my pc (I use the HWE kernel) and I got a dependency error that `xserver-xorg` depends on `xserver-xorg-core`. `xserver-xorg-core` will also remove the `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` package. Would it be better if I changed `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core` to `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg`?

Comment: @mook765 I forgot to tag you.

Comment: @user3140225 No problem, I was looking at it anyway, your command seems to solve it as it removes `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` anyway, so I don't see the need to change the command you provided.

Comment: @mook765 I thought about it and there may be a problem with input devices if `xserver-xorg` isn't installed. So I added it just in case. Thanks for your input!

Comment: this worked after some extra steps that I'll add to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @rm-vanda Sure! Go ahead!

Comment: @rm-vanda Is what you describe in your edit necessary? Or does it just help in some cases? Because I have switched between non-HWE and HWE kernels and didn't have to do this.

Comment: It was necessary for me - I will edit to explain more.

Comment: @rm-vanda You made it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apt log file shows packages that were installed and uninstalled when you run mentioned command.

Just open up:

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
```

and search for:

```
apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

In my case it was important to install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` afterwards for proper touchpad operation.

### **Example is shown below**

***Example what was installed with this command (should be removed now):***

```
Install: xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 (0.28.1-1~18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1, automatic), intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2, automatic), linux-modules-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64~18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04:amd64 (2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.4, automatic), iucode-tool:amd64 (2.3.1-1, automatic), linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.4.0.58.64~18.04.53, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.4, automatic), xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:19.1.0-1~18.04.1, automatic), amd64-microcode:amd64 (3.20191021.1+really3.20181128.1~ubuntu0.18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:19.1.0-1~18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04:amd64 (0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1, automatic), linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.4.0.58.64~18.04.53, automatic), linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64~18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04:amd64 (19.1.0-1~18.04.1, automatic), linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.4.0.58.64~18.04.53), linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64~18.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-58:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64~18.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64~18.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3), xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04:amd64 (1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, automatic)
```

***Example what was removed with this command (should be installed now):***

```
Remove: xserver-xorg-input-all:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1), xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:amd64 (1.9.0-1ubuntu1), xserver-xorg:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1), xserver-xorg-video-qxl:amd64 (0.1.5-2build1), xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 (1:2.3.4-1build3), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 (1:1.0.15-2), xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 (18.0.1-1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.8), xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 (1:0.4.4-1build6), primus:amd64 (0~20150328-6), xserver-xorg-input-libinput:amd64 (0.27.1-1), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.8), xserver-xorg-input-wacom:amd64 (1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1.1), xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 (2:2.99.917+git20171229-1), xserver-xorg-video-vmware:amd64 (1:13.2.1-1build1), xserver-xorg-input-evdev:amd64 (1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1), xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1), xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 (1:18.0.1-1), xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 (1:18.0.1-1), bumblebee:amd64 (3.2.1-17)
```